# XPath queries in IE use zero-based indexes but the W3C spec is one-based. How should I handle the difference?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, xpath, cross-browser

### The Problem

I am converting a relatively large piece of Javascript that currently only works on Internet Explorer in order to make it work on the other browsers as well. Since the code uses XPath extensively we made a little compatibility function to make things easier

```
function selectNodes(xmlDoc, xpath){
    if('selectNodes' in xmlDoc){
        //use IE logic
    }else{
        //use W3C's document.evaluate
    }
}
```

This is mostly working fine but we just came across the limitation that **positions in IE are zero-based but in the W3C model used by the other browsers they are one-based**. This means that to get the first element we need to do `//books[0]` in IE and `//books[1]` in the other browsers.

### My proposed solution

The first thought was using a regex to add one to all indexes that appear in the queries if we are using the document.evaluate version:

```
function addOne(n){ return 1 + parseInt(nStr, 10); }

xpath = xpath.replace(
    /\[\s*(\d+)\s*\]/g,
    function(_, nStr){ return '[' + addOne(nStr) + ']'; }
);
```

### My question

**Is this regex based solution reasonably safe?**

- Are there any places it will convert something it should not?
- Are there any places where it will not convert something it should?

For example, it would fail to replace the index in `//books[position()=1]` but since IE doesn't appear to support `position()` and our code is not using that I think this particular case would not be a problem.

---

### Considerations

- I downloaded [Sarissa](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sarissa/) to see if they have a way to solve this but after looking at the source code apparently they don't?
- I want to add one to the W3C version instead of subtracting one in the IE version to ease my conversion effort.

---

## In the end

We decided to rewrite the code to use proper XPath in IE too by setting the selection language

```
xmlDoc.setProperty("SelectionLanguage", "XPath");
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> we just came across the limitation that positions in IE are zero-based
>   but in the W3C model used by the other browsers they are one-based.
>   This means that to get the first element we need to do `//books[0]` in
>   IE and `//books[1]` in the other browsers.

**Before doing any XPath selection, specify**:

```
xmlDoc.setProperty("SelectionLanguage", "XPath");
```

**MSXML3 uses a dialect of XSLT/XPath that was in use before XSLT and XPath became W3C Recommendations**. The default is "XSLPattern" and this is what you see as behavior.

Read more on this topic here:

**[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms754679(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms754679%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)**

Comment: Do you have any suggestions or references on how to convert from XSLPattern to XPath? Is there anything else I should worry about in addition to the wrong indexing?

Comment: @missingno: If the code you have already uses XSLPattern, then it wouldn't be wise at all to try converting it to XPath -- my best recommendation is to rewrite this legacy code into compliant XSLT 1.0/XPath 1.0.

Comment: That makes sense. But then is there a compliant version of indexing (or at least getting the first element, as this is the most common occurence) or will I have to split queries into multiple parts and do the indexing by hand?

Comment: @missingno: I still don't understand: do you have code that uses the old "XSLPattern" dialect, or not? If not, then you don't have any problem at all -- just use `xmlDoc.setProperty("SelectionLanguage", "XPath");` before you invoke the transformation. This sets the COM object to use the "XPath" selection language -- this is the standard XPath 1.0 that all other browsers are using. With this property set as above, indexing starts at 1.

Comment: Yes it is using the old dialect :(. I am wondering now if it is possible to emulate indexing in a compatible manner ir if I will need to rewrite things like `//books[0]/book` into `doc.selectNodes('//books')[0].selectNodes('/book')`

Comment: @missingno: Why just not use MSXML3 for the transformation? Its default is XSLPattern and it will work OK. Something like this: `var xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.3.0");
xmlDoc.async = false;
xmlDoc.load("books.xml");
if (xmlDoc.parseError.errorCode != 0) {
   var myErr = xmlDoc.parseError;
   WScript.Echo("You have error " + myErr.reason);
} else {
   WScript.Echo(xmlDoc.xml);
}
`  See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms762722(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Oh good grief.  (Looks at hundreds of automation tests that work just fine in Chrome and Firefox. Looks at IE. Sighs...)

Answer (score 1):

Why not modify the original expressions, so that this:

```
var expr = "books[1]";
```

...becomes:

```
var expr = "books[" + index(1)  + "]";
```

...where `index` is defined as (pseudocode):

```
function index(i) {
    return isIE ? (i - 1) : i;
}
```

Comment: How do I know where to call this function though? If all I'm doing is replacing `[n]` patterns by hand then I'm happier with the unobtrusive regex.

Comment: It gets called when the expression is constructed, as in the example above.

Comment: Problem is I have to convert tons of expressions that were originally made by someone else. How do I know where I have to add an `index` call and where I leave things alone?